# Drawbacks of sitting with one leg on a chair

Tags: position

When sitting one the ground I always sit on my knees ([Seiza](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seiza)), because when I try to sit on my buttocks I tend to lie down, and it's just very exhausting for me to sit this way.

So when I sit on a chair, I'm guilty of heavy slouching when I sit on my ass. When I let go, or don't concentrate on it, sometimes my back touches the lower part of the chair, because I just slouch so heavily.
I don't have back problems, because I'm very careful when I crouch or lift heavy objects, but when I sit, I don't want to concentrate on sitting, but rather on my work.

One solution for me was to sit on one leg on the chair and have the other one either hanging or sort of pursed in to the chair.
I can feel that my back is straight when I sit this way, but I always wonder if I commit some atrocity to my legs (esp. knees) whenever I do this.

So are there some health drawbacks to sitting this way? (Also I don't really know how to tag this...)

Comment: I really like user197008's answer below! @hgiesel, would you consider looking into back rests for chairs? Do you have any background that emphasizes back muscle (yoga, dance, sports)? You may easily work on your posture there, and it may or may not leak into your other daily habits. If you do find that you're slouching while sitting up, and don't have the discipline to sit up straight, at least do some stretches to reduce strain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drawbacks of the way you are sitting are:

1. Confine your legs to one position, which can increase pressures under the knee cap and slow circulation to the legs.
2. Prevent you from using your feet to scoot around and navigate your work area.
3. Be tricky to get in and out of.

so, I would recommend you try change your habit of sitting, maybe difficult but it's good for both your health  and your work.